# Como puedo seleccionar el primer elemento de una lista de HTML con javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tengo una lista para mi barra de navegación con todos los elementos como botones ya que es un filtro para un motor de búsqueda, quiero seleccionar el primer elemento de la barra de navegación de forma que, el usuario al entrar a la pagina, de manera automática dicho elemento se le agregue la clase "activo" para que ahora sea "marcador activo".

Codigo HTML

```
    <div class="navegador">
        <div class="contenedor">       
            <nav class="navegacion-principal clearfix">
                <ul>
                    <li><button class="marcador">Todo</button></li>
                    <li><button class="marcador">Finanzas</button></li>
                    <li><button class="marcador">Noticias</button></li>
                    <li><button class="marcador">Politica</button></li>
                    <li><button class="marcador">Economia</button></li>
                    <li><button class="marcador">Firmas</button></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
nav.navegacion-principal button {
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    color: #222;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: transparent;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent
}

nav.navegacion-principal button:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #222222;
}
nav.navegacion-principal button:active {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ff6600;
}
nav.navegacion-principal button:focus {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ff6600;
}

button.activo {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ff6600!important;
}
```

Javascript/Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('button').removeClass('activo');
        $(this).addClass('activo');
    });
});
```

Lo que hace actualmente el codigo de Jquery es que: Al clickar en otros botones se le remueva la clase "activa" al anterior botón y se le sume a la nueva, sin embargo no se como seleccionar el primer elemento elemento de la lista sin utilizar la función de click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa el método [first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/#first) de este modo:

```
$('button').first().addClass('activo');
```

Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').first().addClass('activo');
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('button').removeClass('activo');
    $(this).addClass('activo');
  });
});
```

```css
nav.navegacion-principal button {
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: transparent;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent
}

nav.navegacion-principal button:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #222222;
}

nav.navegacion-principal button:active {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ff6600;
}

nav.navegacion-principal button:focus {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ff6600;
}

button.activo {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ff6600!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navegador">
  <div class="contenedor">
    <nav class="navegacion-principal clearfix">
      <ul>
        <li><button class="marcador">Todo</button></li>
        <li><button class="marcador">Finanzas</button></li>
        <li><button class="marcador">Noticias</button></li>
        <li><button class="marcador">Politica</button></li>
        <li><button class="marcador">Economia</button></li>
        <li><button class="marcador">Firmas</button></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```